# Flutter - Flutter Version Management (fvm) package not working in windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-channel

I just added the the [fvm](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm) package to switch the flutter channel from stable to master without downloading sdk components every time when switching flutter channels.

I have followed the step written in readme.md for switching the channel.

I have set the following path in my environment variables.

```
D:\Program_Files\FlutterSDK\SDK\flutter\bin;
D:\Program_Files\FlutterSDK\SDK\dart-sdk\bin;
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;
```

Now, i have opened my first project in which i want to use "flutter SDK's master channel". But, whenever i try to use the command "fvm use master". It's not working.

It is giving me an error like,
**'fvm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

So, can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Hope you activated the package, using `pub global activate fvm`

Comment: Yes i did it already.

Comment: Here are the options I would try.

 1. If you are in windows 10 you can try `refreshenv`. 
 2. If you are using android studio closing the terminal and restarting by invalidating and clearing the cache could help. 
3. Also you can try running like `pub global list` to make sure it contains fvm.

Comment: Maybe silly but make sure `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;` `user` in this path refers to your username. :)

Comment: Yes did it as well

Answer (score 6):

In my case fvm commands did not work on Windows even tho I checked everything. It gave missing fvm.exe file and other errors. If you also stuck there you can use this way. Only way I managed to get it work is to use longer commands like these:

```
 flutter pub global run fvm:main list
```

Seems like all fvm commands:

```
  config     Set configuration for FVM
  flutter    Proxies Flutter Commands
  install    Installs Flutter SDK Version
  list       Lists installed Flutter SDK Version
  releases   Lists Flutter SDK releases.
  remove     Removes Flutter SDK Version
  use        Which Flutter SDK Version you would like to use
  version    Prints the currently-installed version of FVM
```

Works like this, you just need to add the fvm command to the ending of this - flutter pub global run fvm:main. So add any of them like this form:

```
flutter pub global run fvm:main releases
flutter pub global run fvm:main install 2.2.0
flutter pub global run fvm:main use 2.2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Only this one worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Hi adding in your path:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Pub\Cache\bin
```

More info:

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path

Answer (score 4):

try :

pub global run fvm:main

pub global run fvm:main use VERSION

Comment: Why fvm command not work in VSCode, but work in the terminal application?

Comment: Vscode terminal has probably not refreshed.
You do source ~/.bashrc or source ~/.zshrc to refresh

Answer (score 1):

are you add "C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin" to path?
[image]

if you in windows you should run your text editor as administrator as following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### In my case Error Message was

> Usage Error: Flutter version null is not installed

### To fix this:

1. I have activated FVM by `pub global activate fvm`;
2. Printed installed fvm list by `fvm list`, it should give result as the image below:

[image: fvm list result image]

3. Selected which Flutter SDK version to use by running `fvm use 1.22.0` (in my case 1.22.0, it may differ according to your desired version) command, *It will download SDK if it is not installed yet*;
4. Now you can check is flutter running in your project by running `flutter`;

Also, you can check if the Flutter SDK version set by calling again `fvm list`.
[image]

The tick means, that version is running in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:
**dart pub global activate fvm**

Answer (score 0):

Run as administrator in the project folder and the error is solved.
Example:

- administrator cmd
  C:\Usersers\USURIO\Documents\Flutterproject> fvm use 3.10.0
  project now uses Flutter [3.10.0].

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the .fvm hidden folder in the project and re-run